# HTML textarea height impacting respective row's td height

Tags: html, css, textarea, forms

I recently started working in web development and currently I am working on an html form inside a php script. I have a td with rowspan for textarea. But when I increase the "rows" for textarea, td's in same row starts to expand (here it's Name field td). Below image will explain it
[image]

My code is:

```html
<table style=" width: 500px;">
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px; width: 60px; margin:5px;">*Name</td>
 <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></td>
 <td rowspan="3" style="vertical-align: top; text-align: right; padding: 5px;margin: 5px;">*Message</td>
 <td rowspan="3"><textarea name="comments" cols="100" rows="5" id="comments" class="mtextarea" style="resize: none;"><?php echo $comments; ?></textarea></td>
 
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px; margin: 5px;">*Email</td>
 <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="text-align: right; padding: 5px;margin: 5px;">*Subject</td>
 <td><input name="subject" type="text" id="subject" size="30" value="<?php echo $subject; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="4"><div style="text-align:center"><input name="contactus" type="submit" class="submit" id="contactus" value="Submit"
 style="background-color: #DF1D2A; 
 width:100px; 
 color: white; 
 padding:7px 15px; 
 border:0 none; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 font-size: 15px;"/></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I have tried looking for it online, but still no luck. I don't know what exactly to look for. Any pointers will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Looks fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/esptpmwk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this as it is (as long as those PHP variables are cleansed and free from markup).

You might have some other CSS in the project adding conflicting styles that cause this issue. I would suggest using "inspect element" and looking at the styles applied to the "Name" td and the "Message" td, and the input within. I would selectively disable any extraneous layout-related styles, and see if you can get the issue to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing any issues with the code, although if you only want to update the text area, you could always use the class you assigned to it `'.mtextarea'` and add a width.